# Can wordpress multisite work with multiple domains?

Tags: wordpress, multiple-domains, deployment, architecture, installation

I know that Wordpress supports multisite both in the forms of path and subdomain installations.

For example those:

```
america.my-site.com
europe.my-site.com
africa.my-site.com
```

can reside in the very same WP installation but each one have their own colors, etc. And with multisiete, they share plugin installation, users, etc. as well as the base code so when you update, you do for all micro-sites at a time. You can handle a virtually infinite number of subdomains.

What if I want to host `site1.com`, `site-other.net` and `example-nice.org` into the same WP installation to share plugins, configurations, users, etc, but still have each site with it's own colors, etc?

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Xposted from here https://superuser.com/q/1739324/324451